# The use of "there is the"

Tags: definite-article

I know that "there is the" is less frequently used than "there is a". Having been asking natives on different website about it, I learnt that it's not OK to use "there is the + noun" to point out a location of something.

> - Where is the book?
> - There is the book on the desk.
>
> Not a good usage

Is it really true? Here are some examples produced by natives as well. I wonder if they are all correct.

**1 On the sofa there's a cat. On my bed there's the gift from Mum and dad.**
This one heavily contradicts the so-called rule about not using "there is the" for pointing out a location. Do you find it correct?

**Yet archaeologists deal with priceless objects every day. Second, there is the problem of illegal excavation, resulting in museum-quality pieces being sold to the highest bidder.**

What's the point in "there is the problem"? Why not "there is a problem"?

**There is the word "dodge".**
Would **there is a word dodge** be wrong?

**There is the potential for ambiguity**

Why the? Does the interlocuter know what potential is meant? Isn't it a rheme?

Comment: You are asking two different questions. There's a problem with that. The problem is that the rules say only one question at a time.

Comment: I am not asking one or two or three or no matter how many one may come up with. I am exploring one matter. Along the way, there arise different questions but they all come down to one matter.

Comment: You didn't get what I said. I will say it again, differently: A can become "the" on second use (see my first comment). And, "There is" can be a dummy subject **or** can be used to point at something.

Comment: Where is the construction "there is the" in your saying?

Comment: It has enough focus, Lambie. The issue I raise is brilliant. Downvoting it was...

Comment: You know what? **I did not downvote anything at all**. Why would I downvote and then go to the trouble to providing that looooong answer??

Comment: I take you word for it

Comment: "there is" can be deictic or a dummy. *a* and *the* are determiners.

Answer (score 1):

**There is** the book on the table. [**pointing or deictic**]
There's the book on the table, not the one on the floor. [same thing]

**There is** a book on the table. [**dummy subject**, i.e. the book exists and it is on the table]
Oh look! There is a book on the table. [pointing or deictic]

The determiner *a* versus *the* is always used for general versus specific and sometimes it just depends on what someone wants to say:

There is *a book on the table*. [general statement of fact using a dummy subject]
There is **the book on the table**. [Not the one **on the floor**]
There is the book on the table [that you have been looking for. Same idea as above]

**There is** can be used as a dummy subject to denote the existence of something.
**There is** can be used as a deictic to point something out.

Both can be used with **a** or *the*.

I had **a** car. *The* car I had was a Ford. [Notice the switch from a to the].

In: "Second, there is the problem of illegal excavation" suggests that is the one they are discussing, not another one.

Certainly, that is *a* problem for them. [general] But it could also be: the problem for them. [They don't have others]

Comment: There is the Sun in the Sky. is it a dummy subject or a demonstrative pronoun?

Comment: It depends on what the speaker **wants to say**. Either the speaker is pointing OR it is a dummy subject, **as I explained very clearly in my answer**.

Comment: The dummy subject and the deictic and the use of determiners are two different things.

Comment: Do you think this is correct as well? "Are there the boys still in bed?" I was told it's not.

Comment: @user1425 There are the boys [who are] still in bed [who won't be going] Are there the boys [who are] still in bed? Or is it just the girls?

Comment: Which meaning of "there is" (the dummy subject or deictic") is in "There are the boys [who are] still in bed [who won't be going] Are there the boys [who are] still in bed? "?

Comment: Can you simply say if this is correct or not "Are there the boys still in bed?"

Comment: @user1425 You can't tell just with a written sentence whether a deictic or dummy is intended, **which is why I annotated my answers**. There would be no point to doing that if one could tell from just the writing. //The way you phrased that is bit unusual. On its own, people might say it is not right, which is why I gave you a version that would work in a context and which can be a dummy or a deictic.

Answer (score 0):

Both articles are used, but have different meanings in context:

- "There is a book on the desk," referring to *any* book (e.g., explaining why the desk was not washed).
- "There is the book on the desk," referring to a *specific* book (e.g., that book for which you were looking).

Comment: It's not as simple as you presented it. Usually, "there is the book on the desk" means "There! The book is on the desk!" "There" is not a dummy pronoun but a demonstrative one.